# Winrollback/DeepFreeze How these softwares work?

Tags: delphi, rollback, deepfreeze

DeepFreeze and Winrollback are softwares that protects the hard disk partition of changes. After the reboot all changes, delete, copy, format etc will be restored.

my question is, anyone knows how these softwares work ( programming level )

they use Windows system restore api or something diferent ?

there is any example on internet ? ( already searched and did not find any )
Preferably in delphi (any version)

Answer (score 4):

They use a low level disk driver witch monitors every file system change.Writing device drivers in delphi is hard to impossible.

[Here](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/advanceddelphidriverdevelopmentkit) is an attempt to write drivers in delphi.

Comment: Funny to see that link on the http://www.delphibasics.info site (:
But thanks for the info. Will one day be useful!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few component packages that let you access hardware in both WinNT/2000/XP and Win9x.One of the packages is,TVicHW32 http://www.entechtaiwan.com/tools.htm

Low level disk access packages can be found also here http://ru.geocosmed.ru/pages.php?id=253.

As opc0de suggested it is very hard to do this.

You can take a look also at this question [Bootable and cross platform applications and using delphi or Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235623/bootable-and-cross-platform-applications-and-using-delphi-or-pascal) to get an idea on what has been done concerning creating an OS.

To understand how those 2 software applications work you need to jump into OS architecture and understand how the access is made to disk. A start will be (even I don't like to give links to wikipedia) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system and go further with reading and documentation on the OS you want.